# iTextSharp: center the text in a cell vertically

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to set the text of the table alignment vertically in the middle. I tried using ALIGN_MIDDLE (and ALIGN_TOP) but it only works were there are more than one lines in the cell. With a line per cell it always align the text at the bottom.

This is my cell:

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.SetLeading(0, 1.5f);
cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
```

¿Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Show us a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Your cell is empty, what do you expect to align?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19950711/unable-to-vertically-align-text-in-table-cell-with-itextsharp