# how to align PdfPCell or paragraph using iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

I am creating one table, containing cells with paragraphs. In the paragraphs, I am adding two `Chunk` objects to add an image and three `Phrase` objects to add text and black space as following:

```
var headerTable = new PdfPTable(1);
headerTable.RunDirection = GetDirection(lang);
headerTable.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
headerTable.WidthPercentage = 100f;

var cellLogo = new PdfPCell();
cellLogo.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;

Paragraph pHeader = new Paragraph();
pHeader.Add(new Chunk(logo,0,0)); //Image
pHeader.Add(new Phrase("           "));
pHeader.Add(new Chunk(_localizationService.GetResource("Admin.Commmon.HNLRequisition", lang.Id), labrecFont));
pHeader.Add(new Phrase("           "));

pHeader.Add(new Chunk(imgHNL, 0, 0));//image

cellLogo.AddElement(pHeader);
headerTable.AddCell(cellLogo);
```

Now I want each and every element in paragraph to be aligned but i am getting below output:

[image]

How can I make sure that text and images are aligned.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you're trying to put tabular data into a paragraph? Paragraphs in most writing systems (essentially) bottom-align their content. From your screenshot I'd really recommend using a (possibly nested) table from which you can [very easily vertical align your content](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19956638/231316).

Comment: I definitely concur with @ChrisHaas; in particular as you use a table anyways, you could give it 3 columns and easily align. If you insist, though, on not using table features for tabular purposes, you should look at `Chunk.SetTextRise` to raise or lower chunks.

Comment: Instead of adding images and text to paragraph, i used different cells in composite mode and that solved my problem.